# How do you parse a nested JSON file like below using Processing JSON object?

Tags: java, json, processing

How do you parse a nested JSON file like below using Processing JSON object?  I am trying to figure out how to parse JSON that is multi-level.

```
{
  "info": {
    "description": "COCO 2014 Dataset",
    "url": "http://cocodataset.org",
    "version": "1.0",
    "year": 2014,
    "contributor": "COCO Consortium",
    "date_created": "2017/09/01"
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "license": 5,
      "file_name": "COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg",
      "coco_url": "http://images.cocodataset.org/train2014/COCO_train2014_000000057870.jpg",
      "height": 480,
      "width": 640,
      "date_captured": "2013-11-14 16:28:13",
      "flickr_url": "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3153/2970773875_164f0c0b83_z.jpg",
      "id": 57870
    },
```

Comment: You can use Gson to parse the json and set the value to a model/pojo class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to access nested JSON objects with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997693/best-way-to-access-nested-json-objects-with-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [JSONObject](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray.html) to see the available methods bellow on each page, each with documentation and examples.

Regarding your structure, here's a quick snippet on how you might access nested JSON objects and arrays:

```
// assume data is a JSONObject pointing to the loaded json data (via loadJSONObject / JSONObject.parse(), etc.

// access the info object
JSONObject info = data.getJSONObject("info");
// access the images array object
JSONArray images = data.getJSONArray("images");
// access a string inside an object
println(info.getString("description"));
// access a JSON object inside a JSON array
JSONObject firstImage = images.getJSONObject(0);

// acess an integer
println(firstImage.getInt("id"));
// ... and a string again
println(firstImage.getString("flickr_url"));
```

If you name your loaded `JSONObject` variable `data`, paste the the snippet above and run, it should print:

```
COCO 2014 Dataset
57870
http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3153/2970773875_164f0c0b83_z.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html) to parse/deserialize to model class.

Or if you want to parse manually, then you have to parse a json object first and then you have to parse it again from a parsed json.

Eg.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(jsonString);
JsonObject infoObject = jsonObject.getJsonObject("info");
String description = infoObject.getString("description");
```