# Best way to access nested JSON objects with Java

Tags: java, json

I am new to working with JSON and I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish what I am doing in the below code. You will notice to access a nested JSON object I am having to create child JSON Objects/Arrays before I can get to the JSON array element "leagues". Is there a faster or easier way to do this?

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws UnirestException
{
    JsonNode response = Unirest.get("http://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagues")
            .header("x-rapidapi-host", "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
            .header("x-rapidapi-key", "")
            .asJson()
            .getBody();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject( response );
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray( "array" );
    JSONObject jAPI = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject jLeagues = jAPI.getJSONObject( "api" );
    JSONArray jArrayLeagues = jLeagues.getJSONArray( "leagues" );

    for(int n = 0; n < jArrayLeagues.length(); n++) {
        JSONObject leagues = jArrayLeagues.getJSONObject(n);
        System.out.print(leagues.getString("name") + " " );
        System.out.print(leagues.getString("country") + " ");
        System.out.println( leagues.getInt("league_id") + " " );
    }
}
```

[Link to the JSON data](http://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagues)

Comment: how about [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or jackson?

Comment: Can't say I know much about either, but I will research both. Thanks!

Comment: I personally use gson because of its ease of use and also highly customizability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialise `JSON` payload to `POJO` classes using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Also, these two libraries can deserialise `JSON` to `Java Collection` - `JSON Objects` to `Map` and `JSON Array` to `List`, `Set`, `array (T[])` or any other collection. Using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) you can generate `POJO` classes for given `JSON` payload already with `Gson` or `Jackson` annotations.

When you do not need to process the whole `JSON` payload you can preprocess it using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library. For example, if you want to return only league names you can use `$..leagues[*].name` path. You can try it out using [online tool](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) and provide your `JSON` and path.

Your problem can be easily solved using `Jackson` as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonPointer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // workaround for SSL not related with a question
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();

        String url = "https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagues";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                // ignore JSON properties which are not mapped to POJO
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        // we do not want to build model for whole JSON payload
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(new URL(url));

        // go to leagues JSON Array
        JsonNode leaguesNode = node.at(JsonPointer.compile("/api/leagues"));

        // deserialise "leagues" JSON Array to List of POJO
        List<League> leagues = mapper.convertValue(leaguesNode, new TypeReference<List<League>>(){});
        leagues.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class League {
    @JsonProperty("league_id")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String country;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "League{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
League{id=2, name='Premier League', country='England'}
League{id=6, name='Serie A', country='Brazil'}
League{id=10, name='Eredivisie', country='Netherlands'}
League{id=132, name='Champions League', country='World'}
```

See also:

- [How to ignore enum fields in Jackson JSON-to-Object mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446619/how-to-ignore-enum-fields-in-jackson-json-to-object-mapping)
- [Make Jackson interpret single JSON object as array with one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003823/make-jackson-interpret-single-json-object-as-array-with-one-element)
- [Deserializing into a HashMap of custom objects with jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002132/deserializing-into-a-hashmap-of-custom-objects-with-jackson)
- [Parsing deeply nested JSON properties with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978790/parsing-deeply-nested-json-properties-with-jackson)
- [Create JSON schema from Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783909/create-json-schema-from-java-class)
- [Gson deserialize json with varying value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992891/gson-deserialize-json-with-varying-value-types)
- [Whats an easy way to totally ignore ssl with java url connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257455/whats-an-easy-way-to-totally-ignore-ssl-with-java-url-connections)